# user space program as build-in object

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a user space program and I want to make it as build-in. The reason I am doing this is because I don't want any one to delete the binary file I created and kept in `/root` directory accidentally. I invoke this binary from here

```
/etc/init.d
```

**Questions**

1. Can I create a user space program as build-in obj-y option in my 
   **Makefile**?
2. if so, how do I call it during boot up time or is it that all build in 
   are called automatically during boot up remember this is user space 
   code?

Comment: Everything compiled with kernel is a **kernel code** and will be executed within kernel space. There is [call_usermodehelper](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kmod.c#L616) which allows to call user space program from kernel space.

Comment: Are you trying to create a daemon or a kernel module or something?  You need to clarify, please.

Comment: no this is not a kernel module. for example assume a hello world program can i make it as build-in

Comment: Why are you afraid that someone could delete your binary? What is the scenario you have in mind there? As said by others, you cannot build a user space program into the kernel.

Comment: the product that we sold to our customers who are not from technical background now one technician accidentally deleted few binary files from a /root directory now these were the binary images doing important task of routing when our team had a look at it they were unable to see any logs. finally they figured out there were no binary/executables files now who deleted them and why is out of our discussion. what we want to give our  customer is that they must not be able to delete either kernel image of any files/binary images that could hang/crash the system.

Comment: for example just like android when android is shipped user cannot delete any of its binary images or any files that can hang the system but user can delete only data on the /mnt/sdcard directory which is ok but user won't be able to touch anything under /boot , /sys , /bin , /sbin , /proc i am ok if users are not able to view this directory structure

Comment: In android this is achieved by NOT allowing superuser ("root") permission to the customer/end-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can an userspace program be created using a built-in `obj-y` option in `Makefile`?

**No. Linux kernel makefiles are used to build object files to be linked within the kernel image.**

---

1. If userspace binaries need to be packaged alongwith the Linux kernel image,
   consider using **initramfs/initrd** and build and package it alongwith the Linux kernel image.
2. Next, if the contents of the initramfs/initrd must NEVER be removed at runtime, then one must

   - set the appropriate permissions to the file, directory (deny WRITE access)
     <sub>**and**</sub>
   - restrict access to a superuser account on the system at runtime.

Comment: thanks ThCodeArtist i guess i can use that alternative